# How can I get a User-agent from user request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have to get `User-agent` from a user request and add custom info to that `User-agent` and send it back. 
I have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/new_order")
    public String newOrder(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
        if (isUserNotAuthorized()) {
            return getLoginRedirectPage(redirectAttributes, "/login");
        }
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        // How to retrieve User-agent and add some custom info and return it back to the user?
        return "new_order";
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the header from the request in the following way

```
    @GetMapping("/new_order")
    public String newOrder(@RequestHeader(value = "User-Agent") String userAgent, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
           //...
    }
```

To send the headers back to the client, you can use ResponseEntity

```
public ResponseEntity<String> newOrder() {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.set("User-Agent", "updated-Value");

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
      .headers(responseHeaders)
      .body("New order created.");
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a constant: `@RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT)`

Answer (score 5):

Inject `HttpServletRequest` in your controller method. From there use `HttpServletRequest#getHeader(...)` to get the header you need.

```
    @GetMapping("/new_order")
    public String newOrder(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
        if (isUserNotAuthorized()) {
            return getLoginRedirectPage(redirectAttributes, "/login");
        }
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        // How to retrieve User-agent and add some custom info and return it back to the user?
        return "new_order";
    }
```